# how to get user mobile number in keycloak

Tags: java, keycloak

I am trying to get user registered mobile number in keycloak. 
I am not sure if keycloak does have a method called `getUserByMobileNumber()`, which I can use to get the user mobile number. I have seen people using `getUserById`, `getUserByUsername` and etc.

```
UserModel numberExisting = context.getSession().users().getUserByMobileNumber(mobileNumber, context.getRealm());
```

Comment: did below answer resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve all user attributes from `AccessToken` / `IdToken` (object not string).

For e.g. :

```
KeycloakSecurityContext keycloakSecurityContext = (KeycloakSecurityContext)(request.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName())); 
AccessToken token = keycloakSecurityContext.getToken();
```

This token object contains all fields for user model:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a right direction but I ended up using a method called searchUserByAttribute(), which takes three parameters namely attr name, attr value and Realm. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Updated to Keycloak 21.1.1:

```
List<UserModel> users = context.getSession().users().searchForUserByUserAttributeStream(context.getRealm(), MOBILE_NUMBER_ATTR, "999999999")...collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where **`MOBILE_NUMBER_ATTR`** is the key attribute you're looking for and **`999999999`** is the value.

interface:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/21.1.1/server-spi/src/main/java/org/keycloak/storage/user/UserQueryProvider.java